# How to create swipeable ListView renderer in Xamarin UWP

Tags: xamarin, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I have an application that consists of a `TabbedPage` that holds custom `ContentViews`.

In the main `ContentView` I have a custom `ListView`, that has a `ListViewRenderer` in Xamarin UWP.

The ListView items have a template:

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewItemTemplate">
    <Grid x:Name="grid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--  TEXT -->
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                   Margin="5"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Foreground="Black"
                   Text="{Binding ActualText}"
                   TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" />
        <!--  CC -->
        <my:CustomControl Grid.Column="1"
            ActualCValue="{Binding ActualValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <!--  PICKER  -->
        <ComboBox x:Name="cboxPicker"
                  Grid.Column="2"
                  Width="90"
                  Margin="3"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  ItemsSource="{StaticResource  dataSource}"
                  SelectedIndex="{Binding ActualValue,
                                          Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <!--  SEP -->
        <Border Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                BorderBrush="Gray"
                BorderThickness="1" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Unfortunately, *when I try to use swipe, the tabs are not changing.*

If I use the *built-in Xamarin.Forms ListView* with items consisting of an image and text, it works normally.

***It might be related to the Button's capturing of the focus (assumption).***

What should I change to make my custom `ListViewRenderer` work with swipe?

Comment: I think you mean "If I use the built-in Xamarin.Forms ListViewRenderer..." however I do not see  ListView at al in your XAML. Might help if you could create a MCVE:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was using a `ListViewRenderer`, there was no ListView in the XAML code (it is only provided by the renderer).

The problem however was with the `ListView` *configuration I used in my custom renderer.*

I had this:

```
(Control as SemanticZoom)?.ManipulationMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.ManipulationModes.None;
```

Now I use this, and the swipe works normally:

```
(Control as SemanticZoom)?.ManipulationMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.ManipulationModes.System;
```